# FindBugs stylesheet configuration in my ant task isn't setting correctly

Tags: ant, stylesheet, findbugs

This is what the block in my ant task (build.xml) file looks like.  I'm trying to specifically set it to use a stylesheet in /usr/local/findbugs-1.3.9/source/xsl, but whenever I run it, the resulting findbugs.xml file is looking for a stylesheet at http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/xsl/default.xsl and an error occurs.  Anybody have any ideas?  Finsbugs block below:

```
<taskdef name="findbugs" classname="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.anttask.FindBugsTask"/>
   <target name="findbugs" depends="init">
      <property name="findbugs.home" value="/usr/local/findbugs-1.3.9" />
      <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/test/results"/>
      <findbugs home="${findbugs.home}" stylesheet="${findbugs.home}/src/xsl/default.xsl" output="xml:withMessages" outputFile="${basedir}/build/test/results/findbugs.xml"
                excludeFilter="${basedir}/nbproject/findbugs-exclusions.xml" warningsProperty="findbugs.bugsfound" >
         <auxClasspath path="${javac.classpath}"/>

         <sourcePath path="${basedir}/src"/>
         <class location="${dist.jar}"/>
      </findbugs>
      <!--<fail if="findbugs.bugsfound">Some bugs found; see details above.</fail>-->
   </target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try applying the stylesheet outside the `<findbugs/>` block, like this:

```
<taskdef name="findbugs" classname="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.anttask.FindBugsTask"/>
   <target name="findbugs" depends="init">
      <property name="findbugs.home" value="/usr/local/findbugs-1.3.9" />
      <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/test/results"/>
      <findbugs home="${findbugs.home}" 
                output="xml:withMessages" 
                outputFile="${basedir}/build/test/results/findbugs.xml"
                excludeFilter="${basedir}/nbproject/findbugs-exclusions.xml"
                warningsProperty="findbugs.bugsfound" >
         <auxClasspath path="${javac.classpath}"/>    
         <sourcePath path="${basedir}/src"/>
         <class location="${dist.jar}"/>
      </findbugs>
      <xslt in="${basedir}/build/test/results/findbugs.xml"
            out="${findbugs.dir}/index.html"
            style="${findbugs.home}/src/xsl/default.xsl"/>      
   </target>
```